# Imagemagick's convert errors in python script with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess

I am trying to generate transparent background images with a python script run from the command line but I have a hard time passing all the arguments to subprocess.Popen so that Imagemagick's convert doesn't through me errors.

Here is my code:

```
# Import modules
import os
import subprocess as sp

# Define useful variables
fileList = os.listdir('.')
fileList.remove(currentScriptName)

# Interpret return code
def interpretReturnCode(returnCode) :
    return 'OK' if returnCode is 0 else 'ERROR, check the script'

# Create background images
def createDirectoryAndBackgroundImage() :
    # Ask if numbers-height or numbers-width before creating the directory
    numbersDirectoryType = raw_input('Numbers directory: type "h" for "numbers-height" or "w" for "numbers-width": ')
    if numbersDirectoryType == 'h' :
        # Create 'numbers-height'  directory
        numbersDirectoryName = 'numbers-height'
        numbersDirectory = interpretReturnCode(sp.call(['mkdir', numbersDirectoryName]))
        print '%s%s' % ('Create "numbers-height" directory...', numbersDirectory)
        # Create background images
        startNumber = int(raw_input('First number for the background images: '))
        endNumber = (startNumber + len(fileList) + 1)
        for x in range(startNumber, endNumber) :
            createNum = []
            print 'createNum just after reset and before adding things to it: ', createNum, '\n'
            print 'start' , x, '\n'
            createNum = 'convert -size 143x263  xc:transparent -font "FreeSans-Bold" -pointsize 22 -fill \'#242325\' "text 105,258'.split()
            createNum.append('\'' + str(x) + '\'"')
            createNum.append('-draw')
            createNum.append('./' + numbersDirectoryName + '/' + str(x) + '.png')   
            print 'createNum set up, createNum submittet to subprocess.Popen: ', createNum
            createNumImage = sp.Popen(createNum, stdout=sp.PIPE)
            createNumImage.wait()   
            creationNumReturnCode = interpretReturnCode(createNumImage.returncode)
            print '%s%s%s' % ('\tCreate numbers image...', creationNumReturnCode, '\n')
    elif numbersDirectoryType == 'w' :
        numbersDirectoryName = 'numbers-width'
        numbersDirectory = interpretReturnCode(sp.call(['mkdir', numbersDirectoryName]))
        print '%s%s' % ('Create "numbers-width" directory...', numbersDirectory)
        # Create background images
        startNumber = int(raw_input('First number for the background images: '))
        endNumber = (startNumber + len(fileList) + 1)
        for x in range(startNumber, endNumber) :
            createNum = []
            print 'createNum just after reset and before adding things to it: ', createNum, '\n'
            print 'start' , x, '\n'
            createNum = 'convert -size 224x122  xc:transparent -font "FreeSans-Bold" -pointsize 22-fill \'#242325\' "text 105,258'.split()
            createNum.append('\'' + str(x) + '\'"')
            createNum.append('-draw')
            createNum.append('./' + numbersDirectoryName + '/' + str(x) + '.png')   
            print 'createNum set up, createNum submittet to subprocess.Popen: ', createNum
            createNumImage = sp.Popen(createNum, stdout=sp.PIPE)
            createNumImage.wait()   
            creationNumReturnCode = interpretReturnCode(createNumImage.returncode)
            print '%s%s%s' % ('\tCreate numbers image...', creationNumReturnCode, '\n')
    else :
        print 'No such directory type, please start again'
        numbersDirectoryType = raw_input('Numbers directory: type "h" for "numbers-height" or "w" for "numbers-width": ')
```

For this I get the following errors, for each picture:

```
convert.im6: unable to open image `'#242325'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `'#242325'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `"text': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `"text' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `105,258': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `105,258' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `'152'"': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `'152'"' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: option requires an argument `-draw' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1294.
```

I tried to change the order of the arguments without success, to use shell=True in Popen (but then the function interpretReturCode returns a OK while no image is created (number-heights folder is empty).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend following the this process:

1. Pick a single file and directory
2. change the above so that sp.Popen is replaced by a print statement
3. Run the modified script from the command line
4. Try using the printed command output from the command line
5. Modify the command line until it works
6. Modify the script until it produces the command line that is exactly the same
7. Change the print back to sp.Popen - **Then**, *(if you still have a problem:*
8. Try modifying your command string to start `echo convert` so that
   you can see what, if anything, is happening to the parameters during
   the processing by `sp.Popen`.

> There is also this handy hint from the python documents:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's what I did and that's exactly the thing, the command convert -size 143x263  xc:transparent -font "FreeSans-Bold" -pointsize 22 -fill '#242325' -draw "text 105,258 '152'" 152.png; works like a charm in the command line and not in my script when I "transposed" it

Comment: @IamZesh I have added a step 8 above and possible help from the manual.